# How to show for positive Borel functions $g, \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dF(x) = \int_{a}^{b} g(x)f(x)dx$

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

$\textbf{Problem:}$ Let $\mu$ be an absolutely continous probability distribution with distribution function $F(x)$ and density $f(x)$. For any Borel set $\Lambda$ and $a<b$, let $\nu\left(\Lambda \cap[a,b] \right) = \int_{a}^{b} I_\Lambda (x) f(x) dx$. Show that this defines a probability measure $\nu$ on the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$, and that $\nu = \mu$ . Conclude that for positive Borel functions $g, \int_{a}^{b} g(x)dF(x) = \int_{a}^{b} g(x)f(x)dx.$

I am aware of the following theorem

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution function $F$, and let $g$ be a positive Borel function. Then

$\mathbb{E}\{g(X)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)dF(x).$

In particular $\mathbb{E}\{X\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x dF(x).$

From a different problem I have seen that it might be useful to approach the problem by letting $\mathcal{G}$ be the class of sets on which $\nu = \mu$ since then $(a,b] \in \mathcal{G}$, but I could use some help and direction in how to put this together properly. I for some reason can't seem to make it work and my head is now hurting.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right hand side of the equality correct?

Comment: @Glen_b No, an extra d had gotten in there somehow. I have fixed it now. Thanks

Comment: You need to define a bunch of terms here.

Comment: what is $\mu$ ? And are the $a$ and $b$ in your definition of $\nu$ allowed to be $\pm \infty$ ?

Comment: This is an exercise in chasing mathematical definitions.  Thus, the solution *you* need will depend on *which definitions you need to apply.*  In particular, please let us know what kind of integrals these are (Stieltjes? Lebesgue-Stieltjes? Henstock-Kurzweil? Other?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Albeit the concerns re the ambiguities as shown in the comments deserve clarification, these sort of problems are standard measure theoretic exercises. So, I am leaving below a general brief discussion of the problem in hand following which OP can write the proofs formally.

**Proposition $1.1.$** *Let $(\Omega, \mathfrak A, \mu) $ be a measure space and let $g$ be a non-negative integrable function over $\Omega.$ Then the set function $\mathfrak A\mapsto \mathbb R$ $$ \nu(B):= \int_B g~\mathrm d\mu,~~\forall B\in\mathfrak A\tag 1$$ is a measure on $(\Omega, \mathfrak A).$*

It is obvious $\nu(\emptyset) =0.$ For countable additivity, consider a sequence of disjoint sets $\langle B_i\rangle_{i\in\mathbb N},~B_i\in\mathfrak A. $ Using $\chi_{\cup B_i}= \sum_i \chi_{B_i}, $

\begin{align}\nu\left(\bigcup  B_i\right) &= \int g\chi_{\cup B_i}~\mathrm d\mu\\&= \sum_i\int g\chi_{B_i}~\mathrm d\mu\\&= \sum_i\nu(B_i).\tag 2\end{align}

$\square$

**Proposition $1.2.$** *If $f$ is an extended real-valued measurable function on $\Omega,$ then $$\int_\Omega f~\mathrm d\nu = \int_\Omega fg~\mathrm d\mu.\tag 3$$*

It suffices to show for a simple function $\varphi=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\chi_{B_i}:$

\begin{align}\int \varphi~\mathrm d\nu &= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\nu(B_i)\\ &= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\int g\chi_{B_i}~\mathrm d\mu\\  &=\int \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \chi_{B_i}g~\mathrm d\mu\\&= \int \varphi g ~\mathrm d\mu.\tag 4
 \end{align}

If $f$ is non-negative, then by Simple Approximation Lemma (cf. $\rm [I],$ section $18.1, $ p. $363$) there does exist an increasing sequence of simple functions $\langle \varphi_i\rangle_{i\in\mathbb N}$ converging to $f;$ then $\varphi_i g \to f g.$ The rest follows by Monotone Convergence Theorem (cf. $\rm [I],$ section $18.2, $ p. $370$).

$\square$

**Proposition $2.$** *Let $(\Omega_1,\mathfrak A, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $(\Omega_2,\mathfrak B)$ be a measure space. Let $f$ be $\mathfrak A/\mathfrak B$ measurable. If an extended real-valued $g$ is measurable on $\Omega_2,$ then $$g ~~\mu f^{-1}-\text{integrable}\iff g\circ f~~\mu-\text{integrable}.\tag{5.i}$$ Also, then $$\int_{\Omega_2} g~\mathrm d\left(\mu f^{-1}\right) =\int_{\Omega_1} (g\circ f )~\mathrm d\mu.\tag{5.ii}$$*

Consider $g$ to be a characteristic function of $B\in\mathfrak B. $ Then $g\circ f$ would be the characteristic function of $f^{-1}(B).$ $\rm (5.ii) $ then holds as both are $\mu\left(f^{-1}(B)\right). $ It holds for non-negative measurable $g$ - resort again to Simple Approximation Lemma and Monotone Convergence Theorem. For the general $g, $ it holds true as $g= g^+-g^-$ (from $[\rm II],$ section $2.6, $ pp. $75-76$).

$\square$

Few specifications and additional points:

- If $\nu(\Omega) =1, $ then $\nu$ is probability measure.
- $g$ is a density function which is essentially unique provided $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite; also check Radon-Nikodym Theorem (cf. $\rm[I],$ section $18.4, $ p. $382$).
- Let $(\Omega_1,\mathfrak A, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and let X is $\mathfrak A/\mathfrak B$ measurable. Then $\mathbb P\circ X^{-1},$ the *distribution* is a measure on $(\Omega_2, \mathfrak B). $ Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(\Omega_2, \mathfrak B). $ If the distribution of $X$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t $\mu, $  the associated density being $f, $ and if $g$ is an extended real-valued measurable function on $\Omega_2, $ then, if it is integrable, using the above results,

\begin{align}\int_{\Omega_1} g\circ X ~\mathrm d\mathbb P &= \int_{\Omega_2} g~\mathrm d \left(\mathbb P\circ X^{-1}\right) \\ &= \int_{\Omega_2} g f~\mathrm d \mu.\tag 6
\end{align}

---

### References:

$[\rm I]$ Real Analysis, *H. L. Royden, P. M. Fitzpatrick*, Pearson Education, $2010.$

$\rm [II]$ Measure Theory, *Donald L. Cohn*, Springer Science$+$Business Media, $2013.$